# Fbx textures automatically renamed in Blender

Tags: image

I'm just curious if anyone can tell me why textures names are displayed differently than their file names, even when reimported into the fbx they belong to. This node would normally be named after it's corresponding .png file.

[image: texture node]

Comment: Hello and welcome! How did you reproduce this Bitmaptexture.005? When I add a node with `F3` *> ImageTexture* and then pick an image say "hello.png", it also get's named hello.png.

Comment: Oh thank you. The fbx came with it's own textures, and although the pngs have descriptive filenames, in the image or node editor they are renamed to with this numerical suffix. Files not already in use on the project will be named correctly when imported. 

Maybe the internal names for them were generated automatically at some point?